# LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to localhost:443

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, https, istio-gateway

I was following this doc (https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/secure-ingress/) to set up my Kubernetes on my Docker-Desktop and used istio ingress gateway. I deployed an echo test app, added virtual service that points to the test app endpoint at port 8081. Then I set the istio gateway to open port 443 with the following:

```
  servers:
- hosts:
    - some.random.host
  port:
    name: https
    number: 443
    protocol: HTTPS
  tls:
    mode: SIMPLE
    credentialName: test-app-tls
```

where I also created a tls type secret with name `test-app-tls` using the certs and private key I generated.

(Just in case I forgot to mention something here, I tried with port 80 and http and everything works. Here is an example)

```
curl -i -H 'Host: some.random.host' 'localhost:80/host'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-type: application/json
date: Tue, 02 Aug 2022 21:10:31 GMT
content-length: 148
x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 1
server: istio-envoy

{"name":"some-expected-response","address":"some-other-expected-response"}
```

Then I tried to curl my localhost to hit the test app in the cluster with the following command

```
curl -k -i -v -H 'Host: some.random.host' 'https://localhost:443/host'
```

it gave me this error

```
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to localhost:443 
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to localhost:443
```

I also tried with `https://127.0.0.1:443/host` and still doesn't work.

I'm fairly new to setting up TLS for Kubernetes. Could anyone please help me with this?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Did you find some solution to it?